# Counting non-repetitive words

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

Let $S = \{a, b, c, \ldots \}$ be an alphabet, and let $S^N$ be the set of words with letters in $S$ of length $N$ that are not expressible as the repetition of any single word in $\bigcup_{M < N} S^M$.

For example, `a`, `ab` and `aab` are allowed, but `aa`, `aaa` and `abab` are disallowed.

What is $\left|S^N\right|$ in terms of $\left|S\right|$ and $N$?

I'm also interested in a formula for $\sum_{M = 1}^N \left|S^M\right|$.

Comment: I assume $S$ is finite, say, $S$ has $m$ elements. If $N$ is prime, then of course the size of $S^N$ is $m^N-m$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://oeis.org/A027375 gives the answer for $S$ of size two, with many links to the literature. http://oeis.org/A143324 gives the number of length $n$ primitive (that is, aperiodic, or period $n$) $k$-ary words ($n\ge1$, $k\ge1$) as $$\sum_{d\mid n}k^d\mu(n/d)$$ where the sum is over all $d$ dividing $n$, and $\mu$ is the Mobius function, which see.

Comment: I put yesterday some references around this question. Please comment if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get all divisors of N (excluding N). If $N=30$ you need 1,2,3,5,6,10 and 15.

Then you count all the words of length N and remove all the words of length $d_1, d_2, ...,d_{n_N}$ where $d_i$ are divisors of N with $d_i < N$

$\left|S^{30}\right|=\left|S\right|^{30}-\left|S^1\right|-\left|S^2\right|-\left|S^3\right|-\left|S^5\right|-\left|S^6\right|-\left|S^{10}\right|-\left|S^{15}\right|$

If $N=1$

$\left|S^{1}\right|=\left|S\right|$

If $N>1$

$\left|S^N\right|=\left|S\right|^N-\sum_{M = 1}^{\left|Divisors\,of\,N\right|-1} \left|S^{d_M}\right|$

Some Examples: 
$N=2$

$\left|S^2\right|=\left|S\right|^2-\left|S^1\right|=\left|S\right|^2-\left|S\right|$

$N=3$

$\left|S^3\right|=\left|S\right|^3-\left|S^1\right|=\left|S\right|^3-\left|S\right|$

$N=4$

$\left|S^4\right|=\left|S\right|^4-\left|S^1\right|-\left|S^2\right|=\left|S\right|^4-\left|S\right|-(\left|S\right|^2-\left|S\right|)=\left|S\right|^4-\left|S\right|^2$

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but some references to the main stream (the solution given by Gerry Myerson being correct). As a complement, remark that, if a word is a power (say $w=v^e$ with $e\geq 2$), all its (cyclic) conjugates are such. Your set to be enumerated is then *an union of cyclic classes*. A cyclic class is called *primitive* if it contains no power. Once the alphabet has been ordered, the minimal word (for the lexicographic ordring) of each primitive class is a *Lyndon word*. Have a look [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyndon_word), where one can read

``Lyndon words are named after mathematician Roger Lyndon, who investigated them in 1954, calling them **standard lexicographic sequences**. Anatoly Shirshov introduced Lyndon words in 1953 calling them **regular words**''

Your set, for length $N$ enumerates as $N$ times the number of Lyndon words of length $N$ over an alphabet of size $|S|$. Lyndon words are tightly linked with circular codes, questions about free Lie algebras and algebraic bases (Radford).